# SOLR - indexing the database, configuration

Tags: database, indexing, full-text-search, solr

I am first day with SOLR, and of course, i have some problems with it. I need to index a database, which is postgresql database. I defined fields in data-config.xml file, added DataImportHandler to solrconfig.xml, added postgresql jar to solr folder. But, when i am starting SOLR, i have the following error:

```
2009-10-27 16:08:53.286::WARN:  /solr/admin/
java.lang.IllegalStateException: STREAM
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Response.getWriter(Response.java:571)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.initOut(JspWriterImpl.java:158)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:151)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.release(PageContextImpl.java:208)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.internalReleasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:144)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.releasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:95)
        at org.apache.jsp.admin.index_jsp._jspService(org.apache.jsp.admin.index_jsp:378)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:80)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:373)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:464)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:358)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:367)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:712)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)

        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:268)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:126)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet.doGet(DefaultServlet.java:431)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1098)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:295)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1089)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:365)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:712)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)

        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:211)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:139)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:285)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:502)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:821)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:513)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:208)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:378)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector$Connection.run(SocketConnector.java:226)
        at org.mortbay.thread.BoundedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(BoundedThreadPool.java:442)
```

Any ideas, why i have it? How can i solve it? On web it is : HTTP ERROR: 404

missing core name in path

RequestURI=/solr/admin/index.jsp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything is fine! I was entering wrong url. In my case, according to solr.xml file, i needed to enter localhost/solr/db/admin, but not localhost/solr/admin

Answer (score 8):

I think the best solution for this is to find yourself a stuffed toy.

I'm being serious.

Since I'm a lone programmer and cowboy coder here, there is nobody around to listen to my woes, which almost always end mid-sentence with me realizing what actually went wrong. Sit it on your desk, give it a name if you have to, and talk to it whenever something doesn't add up or just doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure why you were downvoted.  This is a tried-and-true method called Rubber duck debugging. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging

Comment: Dunno how it will look like from a side, cause i'm not alone in office. :)